# Возвращение ссылки на унаследованный класс

Tags: php

Мой вопрос чем-то связан с `tuple` в `python`.

Моя идея заключается в создание двух классов. Первый дает возможность за счет функций задавать данные в класс. Второй же дает возможность получать данные (без возможности редактирования их).

```php
<?php

# Класс для получения данных
class Result
{
    public function get()
    {
    }

    # ...
}

# Класс для вношения данных
class Parser extends Result
{
    public function set()
    {
    }

    # ...
}
```

Я хочу читать файл, и за счет первого класса задавать эти данные в класс(переменную в нутри класса). Но после завершения чтения файла, я хочу давать возможность обращяться только к унаследованному классу (который дает возможность только получать данные).

Напоминает чем-то `tuple` в `питон`, потому что он дает возможность только задать данные без возможности дальнейшего редактирования.

Ну а так же чем-то напоминает `java`:

```java
HashMap arr = new Map();
```

Когда для создание класса объявляется один класс, но использовать должны другой.

Основная проблема в моем случае заключается в возвращение ТОЛЬКО унаследованного класса.

```php
# в нутри функций нельзя написать.
return parent;

# этот вариант возвращяет название класса, а мне нужно ссылку.
return parent::class;
```

Для компиляции использую  `php 8`.

Пример кода:

```php
<?php

class Result
{
    protected array $parameters;

    public function get(string $parameter): string
    {
        return $this->parameters[$parameter];
    }
}

class Parser extends Result
{
    public function set(string $parameter, string $value): void
    {
        $this->parameters[$parameter] = $value;
    }

    public function ref(): Result
    {
        # Так нельзя
        return parent;
    }
}

$parser = new Parser();
$result = $parser->ref();

$result->get(); # ok
$result->set(); # error, эта функция в parser
```

Забыл сказать - я принимаю любые варианты когда есть возможность запрета редактирования данных.
Но лучше было бы, если запрет был не через переменную реализован, а через сам движок, чтобы как раз например не было возможности обращяться к функциям редактирования.

Принимаю варианты и не через классы.
Но сразу скажу, что использовать для этого массив.
Пример:

```php
<?php

$result = array(
    'set' => function ()
    {
        # ....
    },

    'get' => function ()
    {
        # ....
    }
);
```

Я не собираюсь, потому что массив можно редактировать откуда угодно, + нельзя как-то разграничивать область видемости переменных.

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивает реализация стандартных `getter` / `setter` внутри одного класса?

Comment: Для начала надо избавиться от мысли, что `Парсер` наследуется от `Результата`. Конечно нет, это два совершенно разных класса, выполняющих абсолютно разные задачи. Поэтому `Парсер` должен что-то там парсить и __создавать внутри себя__ объект `Результат`, в конструктор которого будут подаваться нужные данные. А `Результат` соответственно будет иметь только публичные геттеры.